# Is there a possibility in DAX to do a distinct over several columns?

Tags: grouping, dax, distinct, ssas-tabular, measure

I'd like to summarize the following ID's with it's prices on a distinct bases. So that means for the ID 123 both prices get summarize cause they are different. But for the ID 789 the price should only count once. So as result I would like to have 8'500 instead of 11'500. I've to solve this problem in DAX.

| ID | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1500 |
| 456 | 2000 |
| 789 | 3000 |
| 123 | 2000 |
| 789 | 3000 |

I tried something like:
CALCULATE(SUM(Tablename[Price]), FILTER(Tablename, DISTINCT(Tablename[ID])), FILTER(Tablename, DISTINCT(Tablename[Price])))

OR

SUMX(DISTINCT(Tablename[ID]), FIRSTNONBLANK(Tablename[Price], 0))

but neither of this works out.

Thx in advandce for your help.
Yannick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution at the end was the following measure:

```
MEASURE Vehicle_dim[dis_sum] =
    VAR vTable =
        SUMMARIZE (
            Vehicle,
            Vehicle[vehicleId],
            Vehicle[Price]
        )

    VAR vSum =
        SUMX(
            vTable,
            Vehicle[Price]
        )
    
    VAR vCnt =
        COUNTROWS (
            DISTINCT (
                SELECTCOLUMNS (
                    Vehicle,
                    "vehicleId", Vehicle[vehicleId],
                    "Price", Vehicle[Price]
                )
            )
        )
    VAR Result =
        DIVIDE ( vSum, vCnt )
    RETURN
    Result
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you are going after out of context. Summing prices doesn't make much sense to me out of context of what you are doing.

This is easy if you can create a calculated table first:

```
=DISTINCT('Table')
```

Then do your SUM against the calculated table.

It's also easy to create the table in Power Query with `Table.Distinct`.

It's difficult to access the column of this calculated table in DAX without creating it first.

Comment: hey @TheRizza 
thanks a lot for your answer. maybe for a little bit of context. I've a table, as posted in my question, with two columns (ID and price) where I try to get out the distinct number of rows (in my example this should be 4, because ID 789 has two times the same entry) and then the sum of price of this distinct rows. as written this should be 8'500.

atm I've a solution for distinct rows:
`=COUNTROWS ( DISTINCT ( SELECTCOLUMNS (table,"ID", table[ID],"Price", table[Price])))`

now how to sum the price from that distinct rows?

p.s.: sorry wasn't able to format properly